# Value not stored in index 0 in character array

Tags: arrays, c, char, scanf

**Problem:** I have been trying to get characters as input from user and store it in a character array using the `scanf()` function in c, but there is no value stored at index 0 of the array. I don't understand why this is happening. This is the code I am  working with,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
     printf("Enter number of characters to store: ");
    scanf("%d", &n); //length of character array
    char ch_arr[n+1];
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    for(i=0;i<n+1;i++){
        scanf("%c",&ch_arr[i]); //get characters from user
    }
    printf("You have entered: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n+1;i++){
        printf("Index %d = %c\n",i,ch_arr[i]); //print the character array
    }
    printf("\nThe character at index 2 is =%c",ch_arr[2]);
    

}
```

The output for the above code is

```
Enter number of characters to store: 5
Enter the string: stack
You have entered: 
Index 0= 

Index 1= s
Index 2= t
Index 3= a
Index 4= c
Index 5= k

The character at index 2 is =t
```

The character at index 2 should be *a*. There is no value store at index 0. Can anybody explain why this occur and how to solve this without using other ways to get input such as `gets()` etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: I recommend that you use `fgets` instead of `scanf`, because in contrast to `scanf`, `fgets` will generally read an entire line instead of a partial line. You may want to read this: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array stores the new line character `'\n'` stored in the buffer after this call of scanf

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

that corresponds to the pressed key Enter. It is seen from the output.

You could write this call for example like

```
scanf("%d%*c", &n);
```

Another approach is to change the loop the following way

```
for(i=0; i< n + 1;i++){
    scanf(i == 0 ? " %c" ? "%c",&ch_arr[i]); //get characters from user
}
```

Or if you want to store a string in the array then write

```
size_t i = 0;
for( ; i < n; i++ ){
    scanf(i == 0 ? " %c" ? "%c",&ch_arr[i]); //get characters from user
}
ch_arr[i] = '\0';
```

Or if you do not want to enter a sequence with embedded spaces then you can write the call of `scanf` simpler

```
size_t i = 0;
for( ; i < n; i++ ){
    scanf( " %c",&ch_arr[i]); //get characters from user
}
ch_arr[i] = '\0';
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.